# Best kayak paint?

Tags: kayaks

Just bought a second-hand carbon fibre kayak and am looking to give it a paint job. What's the right kind of paint (on a budget) for this in your opinions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No idea personally, but if you aren't able to get an answer here I bet if you email/call any of the companies that manufacture carbon competition boats (Jackson/Pyranha/etc) they'd probably be happy to talk to you about the right (and cheap) ways to do it.

Comment: What is probably also important is what you should not take. Obviously, that would be stuff that is water-soluble, but also using certain poisons could be limited by law (as you might be kayaking in drinking water lakes).

Answer (score 3):

You don't paint carbon kayaks.

If there's a coloured gelcoat you can repair that, otherwise you can use fablon (other self adhesive coloured plastics available) to recolour. The joy of fablon being that if you want a new colour next week it comes off with a hairdryer.

This isn't a solution to a damaged hull. Ensure that any gelcoat or resin fully covers the hull and there are no exposed fibres.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it is polystyrene resin construction. If so, use styrene (with activator) with a pigment mixed in.